# Mongodb large document insertion performance optimization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, query-optimization

I am using Nodejs & MongoDB

I have a very simple use-case

I have a collection called `HardwareStore`

I am trying to insert a following record:

```
{
    "title": "Store A",
    "description": "store a description",
    "code": "SA",
    "managerIds": ["afasd32t", "nb92hgsg", .....]
}
```

***Important:*** Array size of managerIds is 10,000

Now the insertion query is taking like 15seconds.

Here is my insertion query:

```
db.collection("HardwareStore").insert({
    "title": "Store A",
    "description": "store a description",
    "code": "SA",
    "managerIds": ["afasd32t", "nb92hgsg", .....]
})
```

Now I am struggling to increase the performance of insertion. How can I optimize this use-case?

Comment: Do you have an index on this field? Apart from bigger computer there is not much you can do, I assume.

Comment: Is _"insertion"_ really the use case?  Perhaps the database/collections could be better modeled for your expected queries?

Comment: it must be a big store if there are 10,000 managers, but regardless of business organisation issues, 15sec  seems a bit too long. Could you share relevant db logs?

Comment: I am flexible to modify db structure. I tried creating seperate collection called: StoreManagers in order to save managerIds there, so while creating store i call a background process which inserts into StoreManagers collection after store creation query. But still the db remains busy and takes time

Comment: @AlexBlex what kind of logs you want?

Comment: I have already created an index on managerIds, doesn’t improve performance

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes insertion is the real use case, I am migrating data from other database to new one

Comment: Hi @StormTrooper, I see this is an embedded relationship between HardwareStores and Managers. Since the array size of managerId is 10,000 i think it will become a large document. The maximum size of a document is 16MB. MongoDB said in their data modeling course if a document becoming a large then the write performance will be slower, and you should considering referenced relationship. 

Please share the size of a document when array size of managerIds is 10,000. Moreover, you can check the anti patterns https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-summary/

Comment: @StormTrooper - the insert record from the profiler: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#view-profiler-data  . Enable conditional profiling with 10,000 miliis threshold - it will log only operations longer than 10 sec.

Comment: @farizmamad  from OPs example, size of the document is **way** below the limit 10k of 8-byte string is less than 1% of the 16MB limit. You will need whole population of a small city to be managers of this store to exceed the limit. It's normal referencing, and it's is actually mentioned in the document that you referred, as a solution to the "big array" antipattern.  You probably missed the context  - they were talking about large arrays of embedded documents. it's not the case here.

Comment: @AlexBlex even if the document size is 5mb, assume that managerIds size is 2000 , and I import 1000 stores, it keeps database busy for that long. thats what I am trying to optimize

Comment: @StormTrooper then update the post with the question. You see, we don't have visibility of all your struggles, only the part that you shared. Now OP reads "time to insert 1 document of size less than 100kb exceeds 15 seconds, how to improve speed". And your last comment is "inserting 1,000 of documents, 5MB each keeps database busy".  These are 2 different problems. You cannot get an answer for the 2nd asking the 1st.

Comment: @AlexBlex My question is the same, if we optimize single document performance, it will improve performance overall, so yeah my main question is still about optimizing single document insertion

Comment: @StormTrooper fair enough. I'd suggest to ignore the hypothetical "imagine if" scenario and get logs from the actual query. There is no one recipe to optimise any query. Well, apart from grow bigger, as WD suggested at the beginning. My point is 15 sec to insert a relatively small document is way too long and must have room for optimisation. You need to do RCA to find the bottleneck, once you know what slows it down you can think about how to fix.